# Hmm , TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
gameRating=0 ;
gameId!:string ;
game!:Game ;
routeSub!:Subscription ;
gameSub!:Subscription;
  constructor(
    private ActivatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,
    private httpService : HttpService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSub=this.ActivatedRoute.params.subscribe((params:Params)=>{
      this.gameId=params['id'];
      this.getGameDetails(this.gameId);
    });
  }
  getGameDetails(id:string):void {
    this.gameSub=this.httpService.
     getGameDetails(id)
    .subscribe((gameResp:Game)=>{
      this.game=gameResp;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.gameRating = this.game.metacritic;
      },1000);
    });
  }
 
}
```

I code a project from a Yt channel and got error and get explaination that its due to the difference between 2 TS verision .

Comment: The error is on line 4 of the getGameDetails  function

Comment: Can you include the code from the `getGameDetails` function in your `httpService` please? I suspect it is missing a `return` statement

Comment: Function getGameDetails inside httpService should return the observable, not the void.